# Can MOSFET withstand the ESD from drain when a TVS diode is installed between gate and source?

Tags: mosfet, esd

- Assume that an N-channel MOSFET is used.
- A TVS diode is inserted between gate and source.
- The source is connected to GND. (Not real grounded (not earthed.))
- The drain is open and connected to the external connector.
  connector is touchable.

Can ESD at the drain connector damage the MOSFET?

- Vgs is suppressed by TVS,
- Drain-source will be breakdown and then charges will flow into the GND.

I have no idea about Vdg rise influence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MOSFET should have a maximum dV/dt rating in its datasheet. Multiply that rating with the FET's output capacitance to get the maximum allowed drain charging current. Any ESD current less than this current should not damage the FET and be dissipated via avalanche breakdown, which most FETs are rated to handle up to an often very large maximum energy.

Let's take the IRF1010E as an example: Max dV/dt is 4V/ns, output capacitance is 690pF typical. 4V/ns * 690pF = 2.76A. The Human Body Model's internal resistance is 1500 Ohms, meaning that a 4kV HBM ESD event (2.6A peak) will not exceed the maximum allowed drain dV/dt and should therefore not damage the FET.

If possible, adding a small capacitor from drain to ground will improve the ESD handling capability further. A TVS diode of course won't hurt either; however, the FET itself can act as a very effective voltage clamp as well due to avalanche breakdown, so an external TVS diode might be redundant. Keeping dV/dt under control is more important for the FET's survival, hence the capacitor.

Comment: Can ESD damage ? If Vgs is protected by TVS and drain-source can breakdown. I think ESD charged energy is not big.

Comment: Drain-source of a MOSFET can break down without damaging the FET, the FET will just clamp the voltage. As long as the gate is protected and the drain voltage doesn't rise too fast(!), there also won't be a gate-drain breakdown.

Answer (score 3):

ESD to drain can result in gate oxide damage.

If drain is exposed and gate isn't exposed, then put the TVS on the drain.  [I see this technique in professionally designed schematics.]

related question: [Are MOSFET drains ESD sensitive?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/463862/are-mosfet-drains-esd-sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an ESD event at drain can damage the MOSFET.

When implementing ESD protection, the idea is to protect the *inputs*, rather than the circuit.
Of course the goal is to protect the circuit behind, but counteractive measures need to be located as close to the ESD event as possible (charges can also "jump" between copper traces).
On the other hand, TVS diodes are not required *within* the circuit, so if the gate is not accessible from outside, you don't need to protect it.